# Show a different timezone for different city, country

Tags: javascript

Help please! I'm trying to show a different timezone for different city, country.(offset/UTC) That way when I set the business hours it will display if its open or close. Here is my JS:

```
var checkTime = function () {
var now = new Date();
var timeDiv = document.getElementById('timeDiv');
var messageDiv = document.getElementById('messageDiv');
timeDiv.innerHTML = now.toString();

var dayOfWeek = now.getDay(); // 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ... 6 = Saturday
var hour = now.getHours(); // 0 = 12am, 1 = 1am, ... 18 = 6pm

// check if it's a weekday between 9am and 6pm
if (dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek < 6 && hour > 8 && hour < 18) {
    messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Yes, we\'re open!';
    messageDiv.className='open';            
}
else {
    messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Sorry, we\'re closed!';
    messageDiv.className='closed';
}
};

setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
checkTime();
```

Comment: Where are you specifying what city and country you want the time zone for?

Answer (score -1):

Using Moment Timezone library you can do some of the following functionality:

**Format Dates in Any Timezone**

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
var dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");

jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 5am PDT
dec.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 4am PST

jun.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 8am EDT
dec.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 7am EST

jun.tz('Asia/Tokyo').format('ha z');           // 9pm JST
dec.tz('Asia/Tokyo').format('ha z');           // 9pm JST

jun.tz('Australia/Sydney').format('ha z');     // 10pm EST
dec.tz('Australia/Sydney').format('ha z');     // 11pm EST
```

**Convert Dates Between Timezones**

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```

you can find the library here: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score -1):

First of all, javascript uses the time of the client machine, that means you don't have to worry about timezones (when you call "new Date()") it will always be now in the client location.

But, for open hours, you need to check in the server side if the shop is in another location (with different timezone), because the client time can't be fully thrusted.

Also, you cannot code timezones functions, you MUST use a library if you still need to deal with it. Why? here is why:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

In your code, I don't see any need for timezones anywhere.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you down vote, I see no errors on my answer, I did not add a link to a library because Seth already did